# "[object object]" on an attribute directive to an object - how to convert

Tags: javascript, json, string, angular

I have an element in angular js that has the data in the following way:

`<some-element zip-codes="[object object]">`

The data is being attached via a service call in node js.

How can i covert this to an object on the FE side?

Nothing seems to be working?

Comment: are you using in angular2??

Comment: JSON.stringify does not seem to work

Comment: Please share component. `JSON.stringfy("something");` might be what you nee but I cannot tell unless I see more.

Comment: You guys are right, I had screwed up.. i just needed to stringify it before attaching to the attribute directive!

Comment: Can you share the component code?????